# custom shapes and change the background image by a button with jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, image, dynamic

Is it possible to have vector shapes and dynamically change the background image by a button in jquery ?

i.e. i need to have a custom shape and be able to have a button that can change the background image to something else..

for instance:

say a star shape with 3 buttons, one saying sheep, one saying dots and one saying solid colour

these buttons change the background image of the star shape with the pre-set images applying to the button names ?

IF that makes sense ??

Thanks in advance

Lee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with a simple square div area and use this code to change the image.

```
  $('#btn1').click(function() {
    $('#divBackground').css('background-image', 'stars.jpg');
});

$('#btn2').click(function() {
    $('#divBackground').css('background-image', 'sheep.jpg');
});

$('#btn3').click(function() {
    $('#divBackground').css('background-image', 'dots.jpg');
});
```

then I would probably lay an image on top of this div with a star shape cut out of the middle to use as a clipping mask.  I might be a little difficult with the CSS you will probably need to tinker with positioning and z-index to get it right.

Another option is to explore the HTML5 canvas functionality, might be some easier ways going that route.

here is a conceptual example:  http://jsfiddle.net/VTQSM/1/

Answer (score 0):

It does not make sense but here is something to get you started:

```
$("#button").css("background-image", "stars.jpg")
```